# "OR" expression with objects does not behave as expected

Tags: typescript

I have two object types and the input of a function can be either one:

```
export default function Eingabefeld({
    isText=true,
    children="",
}:(
    {
        isText: true,
        children:string
    } | {
        isText: false,
        children:number
    }
)) { 
    if (isText === true) {
        let data:string = children
        data;
    }else if (isText === false) {
        let data:number = children
        data;
    }
}
```

Why does TS gives me this error
[image]
as if i would have used the "AND" expression to merge the two object types?

**Edit: It is a TypeScript bug. See:** [Discriminated union parameter destructuring doesn't work if the fields have defaults](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50139)

Comment: What purpose are your defaults serving here?  You [cannot](https://tsplay.dev/mZ4Yew) call `Eingabefeld({})` or `Eingabelfeld({children: ""})` with your original function without error.  If you remove those defaults then [everything works](https://tsplay.dev/wEPdOW) because TS4.6+ supports [destructuring discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions).  I'm happy to write this up as an answer, unless I'm missing something about your question.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218). Please consider changing the `Eingabelfeld` name to something conventionally named (lowercase initial letter for non-constructor functions) and ideally something more suited to an English-language website (maybe `textBox` or something?)

Comment: @jcalz 1. The defaults are there so that by default the type string is chosen if not specified otherwise, so that you could just call `Eingabelfeld({children: "someText"})`. In this overly simplified example it's pretty pointless, but easier to understand.
2. While TS supports destructuring discriminated unions ( i did not knew how they're called. thx) destructuring discriminated unions with defaults like I did, has a TS related bug. See the edit on my post.

Comment: 3. The code is plain text. The error from vscode is an cropped image of the code as to show the error message. I could also copy-pasted the error message, with the loss of styling and positioning as a consequence, but for this case with an easy & short error message i saw it as of secondary importance.
4. The name is almost irrelevant. I could also have written it as an anonymous function `export default function({sText=true,children="" ...`. Another thing to be nitpicking about

Comment: 1. But it doesn't work.  [You can't call it that way.](https://tsplay.dev/mZ4Yew)  Have you tried? Do they serve the purpose you have intended?  If not, all they're doing is exposing the behavior you don't like.  If so, can you demonstrate that?  2. Yes, looks like a bug. 3. Yes, you should copy and paste the error message; the link in my prior comment gives a bunch of reasons why images of code and errors are not recommended; it's not just my suggestion.

Comment: 4. If the name is indeed irrelevant and not something you want people paying attention to, then using an unconventional name is, at best, distracting.  As it originally appeared, I saw "Eingabelfeld" and wondered whether or not that name is supposed to give me some more idea or context for what the function does.  Either way it should be in English, as this is [an English-only web site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange), for better or worse.

Comment: I accept the accusation of nitpicking, since that isn't terribly important.  Still, I thought it would be helpful to avoid such issues by changing the name, so that this question can be useful for future readers.  If you want to leave it alone, that's fine with me.

Comment: In any case, if you have answered the question by identifying the behavior as a bug, you should write that up as an answer, not just edit it into the question.  You may want to edit your existing answer and replace it with a description of the bug and how to work around it.  Or if you don't want to do that I'd be happy to write up an answer.  Let me know what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of solving this.

#### Accessing the properties can be done in two ways:

1. Just don't destructure the object

```
export function Inputfield(props:(
    {
        isText: true,
        children:string
    } | {
        isText: false,
        children:number
    }
)) { 
    if (props.isText === true) {
        let data:string = props.children
    }else if (props.isText === false) {
        let data:number = props.children
    }
}
```

2. destructure it after the if statement

```
export function Inputfield(props:(
    {
        isText: true,
        children:string
    } | {
        isText: false,
        children:number
    }
)) { 
    if (props.isText === true) {
        let {children} = props
        let data:string = children
    }else if (props.isText === false) {
        let {children} = props
        let data:number = children
    }
}
```

#### Applying the default values can also be done in two ways, but it will result in different results:

1. Default values for individual properties

```
type props_type = {
    isText: true,
    children:string
} | {
    isText: false,
    children:number
}
export function Inputfield(_props:(
    Partial<props_type>
)) { 
    const props = {
        isText: true,
        children: "",
        ..._props
    } as props_type

    if (props.isText === true) {
        let data:string = props.children
    }else if (props.isText === false) {
        let data:number = props.children
    }
}
```

this can also be written with more bloating if undefined assignments

```
type props_type = {
    isText: true,
    children:string
} | {
    isText: false,
    children:number
}
function Inputfield(_props:(
    Partial<props_type>
)) { 
    if (_props.isText == undefined) _props.isText = true;
    if (_props.children == undefined) _props.children = "";
    // do NOT use `_props.isText ||= true;`, because if isText is false the default value will be applied

    const props = _props as props_type;

    if (props.isText === true) {
        let data:string = props.children
    }else if (props.isText === false) {
        let data:number = props.children
    }
}
```

2. A default object

```
export function Inputfield(props:(
    {
        isText: true,
        children:string
    } | {
        isText: false,
        children:number
    }
)={
    isText:true,
    children:"",
}) { 
    if (props.isText === true) {
        let data:string = props.children
        data;
    }else if (props.isText === false) {
        let data:number = props.children
        data;
    }
}
```

When defaults are used as individual values, not assigning a property will use the default value. When giving a default object, only if no input object is given, the default is used.

The ways of accessing the properties and applying the default values may be mixed together as needed.

Comment: This isn't the same as your original version because the defaults are gone.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I did an update. A mayor one, i may add, using partial code from the GitHub issue